# Proof for definite integral inequality

Tags: calculus, integration

> Prove this inequality $$ \frac\pi4-\frac12\le\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin x}{1+x^8}\,dx<\frac\pi2-1$$

I have worked with the range of inverse sin which didn't give me anything

Answer (score 0):

Note that $1<1+x^8<2 \text{with} x\in (0,1)$ and this integral $I$ satisfies $\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin(x)}{2} <I< \int_0^1 \arcsin(x)$.

Finally, because the primitive of arcsin is famous, then the inequality after use barrow

Comment: can you explain a bit? I didn't thoroughly understand it.

Comment: I just edit a detail

Comment: okay so the obvious range of one plus the eighth power of X is between 1 and 2 in with the statement of x being part of (0,1)...
but how did you find the ranges of the integral I you referred to?